# How to check if the 'rating' field in present in the results got from Google Place Search?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I want to display a list of restaurants within a radius of my location in a recyclerview. So, I used the Google Place Search API:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.5074836,74.988503&radius=5000&type=restaurant&key=<MY_API_KEY>
```

I am getting the results fine. I use the following code inside a loop to model the returned result into Restaurant class and add it to a list:

```
Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant(
   predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("reference"),
   predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"),
   predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("vicinity"),
   predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("icon"),
   predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("rating"));
resultList.add(restaurant);
```

But, after adding few items to the list, I got the following exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for rating
```

So, I realized that every results may not have the `rating` field. So my question is this, is there any way to filter the results to **only places that have `rating` as the field** or is there any way to **check if `rating` field is present in the result**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has` method like this:

```
if (predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("rating")){

            // here it is safe to use predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("rating")

    Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant(
       predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("reference"),
       predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"),
       predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("vicinity"),
       predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("icon"),
       predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("rating"));
    resultList.add(restaurant);
        }
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. Quick question, won't there be other fields that will be missing from some results?

Comment: In this case, anything could be missing. You can make the same check for any field that is necessary for you and, if there is something missing that you need, ignore the entry. A JSON parsing library, such as Gson, might be of assistance if you are parsing a lot of stuff.